# Special characters

Tags: xetex, symbols, characters

I'm using XeLaTeX to compile my document. If I write in my document `---` I don't get `—`, but `---` in my PDF document. Same for `–` (`--`) character. I'm sure that font which I'm using have this character (Myriad Pro). Are there other ways to get this characters working?If copy&paste this character, it works then. But never when using `--` or `---` shortcuts.

Comment: `\textendash` maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use the option Ligatures=TeX when declaring the font. See the documentation of fontspec.

Comment: Note that, as of version 2.4 of `fontspec`, the option is set by default.